# Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'icon' with value '@drawable/sf__icon')

Tags: sfdcmobilesdk-android

I get the following error when I try to import the VFConnector project from https://github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforceMobileSDK-Android

> SalesforceMobileSDK-Android\hybrid\SampleApps\VFConnector\AndroidManifest.xml
>
>  Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'icon' with value '@drawable/sf__icon').

In the current github, there is no drawable folder under folder "res". Do I need to place images there manually? Or if the github url is of an incorrect version that I should not be using?

Comment: Please is there an answer to this issue. We are really stuck and we have spent many days looking for a solution.
Regards

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem after trying to setup to use forcedroid

My view is there is an error in the template cloned on the create

To work around it, if you look in the platforms\android\res\drawable folder under the project created by "forcedroid create" you will see a single file "icon.png"

The generated manifest is looking for sf__icon.png which does not exist

Copy that file with the name sf__icon.png and the build error will go away